# react-query - is there a way to call useIsInitialLoad?

Tags: react-query

I see in the docs that there is a useIsFetching that returns an integer

is there a way to do useIsLoading? or useIsInitial load for the queryClient?

I've tried searching github issues: * https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+isLoading

- https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+isInitialLoad

And haven't had any luck.

Otherwise, would i just check queryclient if there is any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useIsLoading` is basically:

```
const useIsLoading = (queryKey) => 
  useIsFetching({
    queryKey,
    predicate: (query) => query.state.status === 'loading'
  })
```